# How to find subgroups of index two in this concrete finite group (in an ad-hoc way)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I was doing the following exercise:

Let $G\subset GL(2,\mathbb{C})$ defined by
$\left\{\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\zeta^{a} & 0 \\
0 & \zeta^{b}
\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&\zeta^{a}  \\
 \zeta^{b} & 0
\end{array}\right):\zeta:=e^{\pi \sqrt{-1}/n }, 0\leq a,b \leq (2n-1) \right\}$. This is a finite group of order $8n^2$. And the exercise is: find the subgroups of $G$ of index $2$.

O.K. This is a somewhat "ad-hoc" exercise. The key point is of course computing the subgroup generated by elements $\{g^2:g\in G\}$. Here we can compute this set directly:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\zeta^{a} & 0 \\
0 & \zeta^{b}
\end{array}\right)^2=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\zeta^{2a} & 0 \\
0 & \zeta^{2b}
\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0&\zeta^{a}  \\
 \zeta^{b} & 0
\end{array}\right)^2=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\zeta^{a+b} & 0 \\
0 & \zeta^{a+b}
\end{array}\right).$$
From this direct computation, it can be seen that the subgroup generated by $\{g^2:g\in G\}$ is:
$$H:=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\zeta^{a} & 0 \\
0 & \zeta^{b}
\end{array}\right):a\equiv b(\bmod 2)\right\}
$$
Then counting directly, we see that $H$ is of order $2n^2$, thus of index $4$ in $G$. Then I should try to find a proper subgroup containing $H$. How to do this effectively?

Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestion or hint!

Comment: I would find it easier to work with $\langle x,y,t | x^{2n}=y^{2n}=t^2=[x,y]=1, x^t=y\rangle$. I think it's then clear how to get the derived group and the Frattini subgroup and then (I think) the three elements you need to adjoin to the Frattini subgroup are $t,xy, xyt$. [I hope it's obvious which matrices correspond to $x,y,t$.]

Comment: Use `$\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$` for $\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ and `$x\equiv y\pmod{n}$` for $x\equiv y\pmod{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

Take a subgroup $F$ consisting of all matrices of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\zeta^a & 0\\0 &\zeta^b\end{pmatrix}.
$$

**Addition.**

Since $H$ is a normal subgroup of the group $G$, $|G/H|=4$, and $g^2\in H$ for each $g\in G$,  it follows that $G/H$ is the Klein four-group and hence it has exactly three subgroups of order $2$.   So the group $G$ has three subgroups of index $2$: $F$, $H\cdot\langle a\rangle$, $H\cdot\langle b\rangle$, where
$$
a=\begin{pmatrix}0 & \zeta^n \\\zeta^n & 0\end{pmatrix},\quad 
b=\begin{pmatrix}0& 1\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Yes, this is one case. But is there any other possibility? Can we add some anti-diagonal element to it?

Comment: That is, the problem is to find all subgroups of index $2$. Right?

Comment: Oh yes, that's the problem. First, can I find the number of all such subgroups? (maybe not necessarily write down these subgroups?)

Comment: Besides $F$ there are two more subgroups of index $2$.

Comment: How to see this? I should prove $G/H$ is isomorphic to the Klein four group. Is there any immediate ad-hoc method to do this?